# How to use jQuery input spinner in GridView

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, spinner

I was searching about using an input number for selecting number. I found this [CodePen Sample: Bootstrap 3 input-spinner](http://codepen.io/Thomas-Lebeau/pen/csHqx) and it's good but I have a problem.

When I use it in a GridView when I click on `+` or `-` all inputs change but I want to change only input in that row. How to change codes to use in grid view? My Grid View id is `grdPageLayouts` and template filed is:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="input-group spinner">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAppearanceOrder" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%#Eval("AppearanceOrder").ToString() %>'></asp:TextBox>
        <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same [CodePen Sample: Bootstrap 3 input-spinner](http://codepen.io/Thomas-Lebeau/pen/csHqx) you can attach the `Up(+) / Down(-)` spinners to multiple TextBoxes of the same structure as follows:

```
(function ($) {
  $('.spinner .btn:first-of-type').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=text]').val( parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=text]').val(), 10) + 1);
  });
  $('.spinner .btn:last-of-type').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=text]').val( parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=text]').val(), 10) - 1);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

As the Spinner buttons are in a `<div>` (*child div*) which again is in another `<div>` (*parent div*) that contains your TextBox. So the simple logic is to go up the level as follows:

1. `$(this)` get the current button
2. `$(this).parent()` get to the div that contains buttons i.e. *child div*
3. `$(this).parent().parent()` get to the div that contains your TextBox i.e. *parent div*
4. `$(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=text]')` find your TextBox control

You can view updated [CodePen Sample](http://codepen.io/haraman/pen/yYRbwL)